# Connecting Android with Web Server

Tags: php, android, database, security, lockdown

This has been stumping me for awhile now. I'm looking to connect an Android app to a web server using PHP. How would one go about securing the web server and only allowing Android app users to connect, and locking out browser users and other users that can manipulate headers and regular authorization? How can I differentiate between a legitimate Android user and one acting like Android user?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look into [mutual authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). Use the keystore that you use to sign your apk[[related]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848141/ssl-client-authentication-in-android). The client authenticates the server *and* the server authenticates the client. This way only clients that are signed by you will be able to connect to your server.